# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function parallelevents() in php

Tags: php

What I need:

I'm using call by value to pass the data in another functions.

Step 1. I tried to pass value like this :-

```
    parallelEvents( $data['data']['venue']['venue_id'],$data['data']['event']['event_startdate'],$data['data']['event']['event_enddate']);
```

and call in function

```
     parallelEvents($vanueid,$startdate,$enddate)
     {
   echo "test";
     }


  output: 500
```

Step 2. I tried to call like this.

```
 call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parallelEvents'),  
 array($data['data']['venue']['venue_id'],
 $data['data']['event']['event_startdate'],
 $data['data']['event']['event_enddate']));
```

call like this

```
public function parallelEvents($venueid,$startdate,$enddate)
{
    echo $venueid;
 }
```

output: ok

step 3. now using function in another function.

```
public function aboutEvent()
{
   parallelEvents($venueid,$startdate,$enddate);
 }
```

output : PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function parallelEvents()

Please, someone suggest where I'm doing wrong.

I need to pass value in another function.

Comment: Well step one is missing the `function` keyword or `public function` if its in a class

Comment: And step 2, well you should look up how to use call_user_func_array(), it, as the error states, takes only 2 parameters. Your parameters should be in an array().

Answer (score 0):

[call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func-array.php) expects 2 parameters :

```
1 - function name,
2 - Arguments.
```

--

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parallelEvents'), 
array($data['data']['venue']['venue_id'],
      $data['data']['event']['event_startdate'],
      $data['data']['event']['event_enddate']));
```

Comment: i have problem in step 3 while calling again in  function

Comment: then it throws undefined values $venueid,$startdate,$enddate

Comment: public function aboutEvent($venueid,$startdate,$enddate)
{
   $this->parallelEvents($venueid,$startdate,$enddate);
 }